# how to make a dynamic xml using java

Tags: java, xml

I have a fixed template of XML and the nodes may increase as per the data.
If I have a fixed template. How to iterate all the child nodes when the parent node name is being supplied?
Can I make a XML based on the xpath?

I have the follwoing code:-

```
Map map = hm(); 
            Set set = map.entrySet(); 
            // Get an iterator 
            Iterator it = set.iterator(); 
            // Display elements 
            while(it.hasNext()) { 
                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next(); 
                if (check) {
                    xpath_String+= "|"+me.getKey(); 
                }else {
                    xpath_String+= me.getKey();
                    check = true;
                }           
            }

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        //xml file name acts as template
        Document doc = builder.parse("template.xml"); 


        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath(); 
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpath_String);  
        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result; 
        System.out.println("Total number of tokens: "+nodes.getLength());
        //for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

        int i=0;

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(xpath_String,"|");

        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String val = (String) st.nextElement();
            if(hm().containsKey(val)){
                System.out.println("Node value is: "+nodes.item(i).getNodeName());
                nodes.item(i).setTextContent(hm().get(val).toString());
                i++;
            }
        }
        //}

        //write the content into xml file
         TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
         // generating the output file name
         StreamResult finalResult =  new StreamResult(new File("newfxml.xml"));
         transformer.transform(source, finalResult);

         //making a string for the dom
         StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
         StreamResult stResult = new StreamResult(writer);
         transformer.transform(source, stResult);
```

Here I have a fixed template and I a map. from the map I am getting the xpath and its corresponding values. This hold only good until none of the nodes in the template xml repeats itself. So i was wondering if There is any way I can iterate the whole chunk of xml node when I get a repeatable component.
Is there any solution like this ?
Or I need to change way I m intending to proceed??

Comment: Post an example of your xml. Then tell us what have you tried. Then tell us where did you get stuck. Then tell us what you really want, by example.

Comment: Do you have an XSD? If so you can use something like XMLBeans.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enumerate all the children of a node, you just need to get your parent node with something like 'Element parent = root.getChild("parentNodeName")' then you can enumerate the children with the same methode 'List children = parent.getChildren("childName")'.

```
    Document doc = null;
    SAXBuilder sxb = new SAXBuilder();
    try {
        doc = sxb.build(new File(MyXmlFilePath));
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Element root = doc.getRootElement();
    List<Element> nodes = root.getChildren("myNode");
    Iterator<Element> it = nodes.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Element currentNode = it.next();
        // node treatment here
    }
```

Anhuin.

Comment: this is gud but my requirement is to make a xml as per the template provided. This holds good till I get all the elements of the node, but even if i don't get the element I need to populata the node with blank value. Moreover as per the need the complete thing needs to be generic by virtue of which I cannot directly use mention the tagname of the element.